# Count occurrences in a table and print both the count and the rank

Tags: php, mysql

In my Events table I have a column called Pos1, which contains IDs from A to E.  I need to count how many times 'E' appears in the column and where it ranks alongside the other numbers.

For example in this table 'E' occurs **1** time and is ranked **4** (D=3, A=2, C=2, E=1, B=0).

```
Pos1
E
C
D
C
D
D
A
A
```

I'm a complete SQL amateur so the closest I've got is an array printing the count of each ID, but I need this to be limited to counting a single ID *and* printing the rank.

```
$query = "SELECT Pos1, COUNT(Pos1) FROM Events GROUP BY Pos1"; 

$result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){

    echo $row['COUNT(Pos1)'] ."<br />";

}
```

Comment: Would be soooo easy if MySQL supported windowing functions...

Comment: Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions to write new code. They are no longer maintained and the community has begun [deprecation process](http://goo.gl/KJveJ). See the *[red box](http://goo.gl/GPmFd)*? Instead you should learn about [prepared statements](http://goo.gl/vn8zQ) and use either [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli). If you can't decide which, [this article](http://goo.gl/3gqF9) will help you. If you pick PDO, [here is good tutorial](http://goo.gl/vFWnC).

Comment: Thanks Truth. I tried mysqli_ for a few of them instead, but it didn't work. I guess it's a whole different structure rather than a simple replacement.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

try this:

```
SELECT Pos1, a.cnt, rank
FROM(
    SELECT a.Pos1, a.cnt, (@rank := @rank + 1) AS rank
    FROM(
        SELECT Pos1, COUNT(Pos1) cnt
        FROM Events
        GROUP BY Pos1
    ) a, (SELECT @rank := 0) b
    ORDER BY a.cnt DESC
)a
WHERE a.pos1 = 'E';
```

[SQLFIDDLE DEMO HERE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a1e4e/2)

EDIT: php code

```
$query = "SELECT Pos1, a.cnt, rank
          FROM(
            SELECT a.Pos1, a.cnt, (@rank := @rank + 1) AS rank
            FROM(
                SELECT Pos1, COUNT(Pos1) cnt
                FROM Events
                GROUP BY Pos1
            ) a, (SELECT @rank := 0) b
            ORDER BY a.cnt DESC
          )a
          WHERE a.pos1 = '$pos1'";

$result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());

$row = mysql_fetch_row($result);

echo $row['Pos1']." ".$row['cnt']." ".$row['rank']."<br />";
```

Comment: Interesting. Never thought about using a subselect to initialize a variable, I've always done the `SET @rank = 0;` first instead. Neat!

Comment: This looks good - can you help me out with the php to display it on the page?

Comment: ya sure. you just need to substitute the value for php variable `pos1` in query.

Comment: Thank you. Just one issue that I had to figure out - row=mysql_fetch_row($result) should be row=mysql_fetch_array($result);

Comment: `mysql_fetch_array` will also work. In this case you can use `mysql_fetch_row` as we are fetching only single row. See this http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-row.php

Answer (score 0):

alternatively do rank within PHP:

```
$query = "SELECT Pos1, COUNT(Pos1) AS qty FROM Events GROUP BY Pos1 ORDER BY qty DESC"; 

$result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
$rank=1;
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
    echo $rank.": ".$row['Pos1']."(".$row['qty'].")<br />";
    $rank++;
}
```

Comment: The other answer has vanished, but would have allowed you to just get the ranking of E alone.

Comment: I just deleted it for some time as I found some major error after posting it. It's working now. :)